# How to install OCaml modules?

Tags: module, ocaml

```
# open Std;;
Characters 0-8:
  open Std;;
  ^^^^^^^^
Error: Unbound module Std
```

Run in the `ocaml` interpreter. I had previously installed `ocaml-extlib-devel` and `ocaml-extlib`. What else do I need to do to get the module installed?

(I'm working on RedHat Linux, FC-18).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is:

```
#use "topfind";;
#require "extlib";;
```

You need to type those `#`, in additional to the prompt, because those are toplevel directives. They use the library `findlib` which also provides the `ocamlfind` tool and is probably installed in your OCaml environment (otherwise you should get it installed). It knows where to find ocaml packages in your filesystem.

Comment: Thanks, for those who don't have `topfind` installed (I didn't), it's in the `ocaml-findlib` package.

Comment: I recommend you to use utop instead of the classical repl.
You can easily install utop by using opam http://opam.ocamlpro.com/doc/Quick_Install.html